# PHP filter for WooCommerce product description

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on a webstore and need to filter my discription text.
My data gives me unicodes that need to be filtert out.

I have the filter part wrking but need to filter the product description.

A filter I found realy close is `add_filter('woocommerce_product_description_heading', 'filter_unicode')`. But this is for the header of the description. I also tried `woocommerce_product_description_content` but this was without any sucsess.

Does anyone know what filter i need to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out (finnaly),

I gave up on that spesiffic string.

I did it by using `ob_start("filter_unicode")`;

This will filter the whole content!

**My code:**

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'start_filter_page');
add_action('shutdown', 'end_filter_page');

function start_filter_page() { 
 ob_start("filter_unicode"); 
} 

function end_filter_page() {
 if(ob_get_length() > 0) {
    ob_clean();
 }
}
```

The `ob_start("filter_unicode");` will start the function `filter_unicode()` where i manipulate the string.